# Homomorphisms and isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If a homomorphism has a trivial kernel, is it an isomorphism?

Comment: Not unless you assume a bunch of extra things. Try a few simple examples to see this.

Comment: An isomorphism's image must be the whole codomain.

Comment: I just realized that using the word "simple" might have been a bad choice, as if one interprets that as the objects being simple, that is one of the cases where the above is actually true.

Comment: *Exercise:* Show that an homomorphism $f$ is injective iff has trivial kernel.

But you cant conclude that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Yea your right. its only injective. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Recall: **An isomorphism is a *bijective* homomorphism.**

We need more conditions on a homormorphism whose kernel is trivial to ensure it is an isomorphism:

> A homomorphism whose kernel is trivial *is injective*, but *not* necessarily onto, hence not necessarily an isomorphism.

Comment: More precisely, an isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism whose inverse is a homomorphism. This is not automatic in all categories, e.g., topological spaces.

Answer (score 3):

It is not that actually. Even if you consider this identity map for example: $i:A_n \rightarrow S_n$ sending each $\tau$ to itself. $A_n$ is not isomorphic to $S_n$ right?

Ontoness is also necessary for an homomorphism to be an isomorphism. If you have an injective homomorphism which is not necessarily onto, then it is called an *embedding*.

Answer (score 1):

An isomorphism is a homomorphism that is injective(1-1) and surjective(onto), but the trivial kernel makes it a monomorphism not necessarily surjective.